# Print plain output with only a space in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with following columns and index  :

```
   first  sec
0    z     50
2    b     3
1    a     3
4    c     2
5    e     1
```

I want to print this plain output :

```
z 50
b 3
a 3
c 2
e 1
```

I have used to_string , but its not giving desired results , i have used some loops too , but nothing is giving desired results

Comment: Are the columns guaranteed to take one character?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, I just updated the question , first column will alwasys take one character , second column can have multiple characters just like I did in my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) specifying `header` and `index` to be `None`

```
>>> print(df.to_string(header=None, index=None))

z   50
b   3
a   3
c   2
e   1
```

---

If you want *exactly* your output, you can play with the series by adding *exactly one* space and then your next series.

```
>>> x = df['first'].add(' ').add(df['sec'].astype(str)).to_string(index=None).replace('\n ', '\n')

z 50
b 3
a 3
c 2
e 1
```

Comment: spaces are many , i want something like exactly in my question